# Loop Std object array from SOAP to Database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, soap

Getting soap response as STD object.
I'm trying to put this into a mysql database.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($getrelaties); $i++) {
    $array = get_object_vars($getrelaties[$i]);
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
    print "</pre>";
    print "<hr>";

    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        echo $key;
        echo $val;
    }
};
```

Im getting the keys (wich are the row names) and values. But kinda stuck on getting them to be seperated by , so I can put them in a query
this is one array out of the object.

```
(
    [ID] => 4876260
    [AddDatum] => 2015-09-24T09:16:00
    [Code] => K0001
    [Bedrijf] => Henk
    [Contactpersoon] => 
    [Geslacht] => m
    [Adres] => 
    [Postcode] => 
    [Plaats] => 
    [Land] => 
    [Adres2] => 
    [Postcode2] => 
    [Plaats2] => 
    [Land2] => 
    [Telefoon] => 
    [GSM] => 
    [FAX] => 
    [Email] => ******@gmail.com
    [Site] => 
    [Notitie] => 
    [Bankrekening] => 
    [Girorekening] => 
    [BTWNummer] => 
    [Aanhef] => 
    [IBAN] => 
    [BIC] => 
    [BP] => B
    [Def1] => 
    [Def2] => 
    [Def3] => 
    [Def4] => 
    [Def5] => 
    [Def6] => 
    [Def7] => 
    [Def8] => 
    [Def9] => 
    [Def10] => 
    [LA] => 0
    [Gb_ID] => 0
    [GeenEmail] => 0
    [NieuwsbriefgroepenCount] => 0
)
```

The problem is that I want to put these arrays into the database .
I dont want to hardcode the rows.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to stringify the array and store in a BLOB or TEXT field in MySQL:

```
$serialized_array = serialize($array);
```

You can then `SELECT` this data back from the database as needed and make use of:

```
$data = unserialize($serialized_array);
```

This is 100% the way to go because the format of the arrays returned from the third-party SOAP service could change over time and you are not at the mercy of these changes and having to detect them and migrate your database schema accordingly etc.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, serialize the full std object to 1 field in database, then unserialize it to display or use the data? .. please explain :)

Comment: @user3119386 yes, store each distinct array as needed and makes sense for your application, making use of `unserialize()` to reformat from a representative string to a useful PHP again.

Comment: @user3119386 has this solved your question? Would you might upvoting/accepting my answer if so? Thanks :)